# Is it possible to create these charts using Chart.js?

Tags: d3.js, chart.js, react-chartjs

I need to create the following two charts:

[image: horizontal bar chart]

[image: Circular chart]

I'm guessing the first one should be possible with Chart.js? But I'm unsure about the second. If not possible, do you know what libraries I could use? D3, or another chart library?

(I'm using React/NextJS.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious about your solution.

Comment: I used HTML canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/grantrules/rc2Lq563/